# Average all values for a each field date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, average

I'm trying to build a web app that analyzes survey results about movies, that are uploaded to the system manually by an administrator. The results are uploaded based on the date the survey was fielded. There are a number of different categories surveyed and each respondent inputs a number response (from 1-7) for each category, for each movie. I have set up the system so that on the movies index page, you can select a movie and it will bring you to that specific movie's show page on the site. What I'd like to be able to do is have the system display only the averages of the survey results (by category) based on each field date, in a table.

Example raw results input by admin:

```
Field Date: 03/23/2013, Interesting:5, Trendy: 6, Funny: 3
Field Date: 03/23/2013, Interesting:6, Trendy: 6, Funny: 7
Field Date: 03/29/2013, Interesting:2, Trendy: 4, Funny: 3
```

Example of what I want to output in table:

```
Field Date: 03/23/2013, Interesting:5.5, Trendy: 6, Funny: 5
Field Date: 03/29/2013, Interesting:2, Trendy: 4, Funny: 3
```

Here is my schema:

```
create_table "movies", :force => true do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.string   "category"
 t.date     "field"
end

create_table "results", :force => true do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.date     "field"
 t.integer  "movie_id"
 t.integer  "interesting"
 t.integer  "trendy"
 t.integer  "funny"
end
```

Here is the table in my movies show page:

```
<% @results.order('field DESC').each do |resultz| %>
  <tr class="tableline" >
    <td class="tableline"><%= resultz.field %></td>
    <td class="tableline"><%= resultz.interesting %></td>
    <td class="tableline"><%= resultz.trendy %></td>
    <td class="tableline"><%= resultz.funny %></td>
  </tr>
```

Currently that shows all raw values uploaded by the admin. I think I need to use the average method along with the :group option, but for some reason when I try that out it keeps giving me errors. I don't think DATE_TRUNC works because I'm using sqlite3, though I'm not sure if that's the right reasoning.

Any help would be greatly appreciated (even linking to the appropriate documentation)! Thanks!

Comment: What is the data type for your `Interesting`, `Funny` attributes etc? After activerecord query, if we typecast them back to those, it will retain the same type.

Comment: The three attributes should be integers.

Comment: I meant, after average what it should be? As per your example case above: `Field Date: 03/23/2013, Interesting:5.5, Trendy: 6, Funny: 5`, Interesting has 5.5 value, but I guess, it is made for integer type.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I think float would be appropriate.

Comment: Hm. To give back the float result in those integer containers `Interesting`, `Funny` etc is not possible.

Comment: Hmm, to be honest, I'm not entirely sure which data type would be best. Is there one that I should be using?

Comment: You can make base type of them as float. This way, general data can be saved as normal integers, and with aggregating activerecord query, we can fill in the floating averages for them by group.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but for other values on the page I've been able to create something like this in my model and it provides a decimal value: 

`def average_interesting
    self.class.average(:interesting)
end`

Is there a reason I can't add a condition or group to that to solve this problem?

Comment: That is a bad way of doing that. First, it should have been class method `def self.average_interesting`, secondly, just `average(:interesting, :group => 'DATE(field_date)') end`. You will end up making methods for each such attribute, which isn't you actually want. This will also lead to multiple database queries -> Less performance.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord does have `average` for finding average of a *column* and allows options such as  `:group`. But, it works for a single column at a time.
For this situation, it is generally advised to make your own sql query, or use something chainable like below:

```
@fields = Field.group('DATE(field_date)').
  select('avg(interesting) as interesting, 
         avg(funny) as funny,
         avg(trendy) as trendy')
```

Hope it helps. I would love to see some good solution for this, if present. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the SQL query you need to execute in your controller is this:

```
SELECT field, AVG(interesting), AVG(trendy), AVG(funny) FROM results WHERE movie_id =
<movie_im_at_show_page_for> GROUP BY field
```

In Rails that will look something like this:

```
@results = Results.find(select: "field, AVG(interesting), AVG(trendy), AVG(funny)", 
conditions: ["movie_id = ?", <movie_im_at_show_page_for>], group: "field")
```

You'll have to replace `<movie_im_at_show_page_for>` with the actual ID. I'd think that would look something like `@movie.id` in your controller.